# Create files/folders upon npm install custom package

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

I'm attempting to write an npm package/framework for my own private use, and something that I'd like it to do is to automatically create a series of files and folders that I'll need. This seemed like a fairly simple task:

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build-fs": "node build.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run-script build-fs"
  },
  "author": "...",
  "license": "...",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1"
  }
}

//build.js
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
mkdirp('./src', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

As you can see, I've simply set up a script to run after the install process is complete. But it doesn't work. I `npm pack` my module, move the resulting `.tgz` file into another directory and then `npm install`. It runs fine, and I can see that my `build.js` script is being run with no error, but no new directory is created.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think folder permission might be an issue. Try giving permission to the directory folder and run again.

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you